# EditTextPreference with false persistent does not call onSharedPreferenceChanged

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I've this EditTextPreference

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:title="@string/settings_server"
        android:summary="@string/server_name_message"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:key="SERVER_NAME" />
```

But with persistent="false" it does not call `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method.
How can I detect this event keeping `android:persistent="false"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to attach custom listener in code of your `PreferenceActivity` or `PreferenceFragment`:

```
EditTextPreference prefServerName = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("SERVER_NAME");

prefServerName.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        String value = (String) newValue;

        // do what you need

        return true; // indicates you processed the new value
    }
});
```